# Next-gen technologies to anticipate for development?

Tags: game-design, planning

From the point of view of pure game design and planning, what are the technologies of the next-gen (post-360, PS3, and wii) consoles that I can anticipate for my design?  In designing a new game, I want to leave it open-ended enough to incorporate the new technologies and start planning for future gameplay.  Depending on the technologies, I might also want to change the style of gameplay.

Comment: Only if the inputs available change will a game design change, the rest of the technology is irrelevant.

Comment: No one knows what new technologies will be successful and which ones won't. Any answer to this question would be purely a guess. It might be better to ask your question in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: You could start another question that would be more general and therefore more useful, maybe something like: "How do I create a game design that can adapt to new platform environments?" or maybe "How have game designs changed for each new generation of hardware?" and extrapolate your own answer from that discussion.

Comment: @Patrick, I like that first question, it's basically what I'm wondering and trying to plan for.  Should I delete this question?

Comment: This question looks to close very soon, wait for that event and then fire up that new one and kick start it with anything you got out of this one.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of your question depends on the type of game you are making. Recently, the big 3 game consoles have put a lot of effort into motion control based systems, and personally I expect that trend to continue.

However, there are 2 distinctly different approaches at this time. The Wii / PS3 approach involves handheld controllers combined with motion. The 360's Kinect eliminates the controller entirely and relies on pure player movement. Both have been relatively successful, so it is hard to anticipate which approach will be more adopted in the future.

Comment: The Wii was extremely successful, but has it changed the way we look at and design games? Not to my knowledge.

Comment: dreta: I argue that it absolutely has, but only if you are intending to develop a game for that system / control style. A game that is designed for traditional control mediums will fail miserably on the Wii. Motion based games require a different approach.